# BitmapShader as a source for a Paint path

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Is it possible using non-openGL to achieve the effect shown in the graphic. Basically the stroke width is the same throughout the path as is the source bitmap. Before you're wondering why, Paint.setMaskFilter is quite slow. I'd rather prerender a blur in a bitmap and just paint with that.

Code for what it's worth:

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(40f);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(8f));
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shader_source);
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bm, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(shader);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`?